# URL Map is not working with backend service on Load Balancer Google Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, url-mapping

I am setting up URL Maps on our Backend Services with Load Balancer. The issue is that my URL Maps are not working for some reason. When I tried to browse domain.com/path, it shows

> The requested URL /bpd was not found on this server.

I do believe I did the correct way, but seems that its still not working.

Please see screenshot below:

[![image][1]][1]

/* - working

/path1 and /path2 - not working, shows error - was not found on this server

app.yaml file:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
service: 
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: 
  upload: 
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
```

I also set-up Serverless network endpoint group and connected with Google App Engine for the Backend Services.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Do you have logs on your backed? Do you see some inbound request but hitting the wrong path?

Comment: In addition to the Guillaume's comment, how is your app.yaml configured?

Comment: I didnt see any inbound logs too @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: @SamuelRomero I added my yaml config

Comment: how do you call, for example, address-verifier backend with a curl (which work)? Can you show me the pattern?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere

https://cloud.myccw.us
https://cloud.myccw.us/address/
https://cloud.myccw.us/bpd/

All services are connected to IAP so expect google login will prompt

Comment: It wasn't my question. If you call directly the backend, without the load balancer, on a URL like that `address-verifier.appspot.com/address/something`, do you have the correct answer from the service? (after the IAP authentication and so on) Or doyou have a 404 also?

Comment: Ahh. Here:

https://address-verifier-dot-mpa-cloud-266623.appspot.com/

This will work without IAP @guillaumeblaquiere

So I need this to be accessed using https://cloud.myccw.us/address

Comment: Perfect, now, new question: Is something exist at this url or do you get a 404? `address-verifier-dot-mpa-cloud-266623.appspot.com/address/something` (change the something to get real content, if any)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere

Error: Not Found
The requested URL /address/ was not found on this server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to your comment, I though I found the mistake. In fact, when you define a URL map in a load balancer, the query path in entry of the load balancer is, by default, forwarded as-is to the backend.

Let's take your case

- you have this URL map: `<URL>/address/*`. Your URL path is `/address/*`
- The backend is `<myAddressAppEngine.appspot.com>`. It received the request on this path `<myAddressAppEngine.appspot.com>/address/*`

And it doesn't work because in reality you expect `<myAddressAppEngine.appspot.com>/*`.

---

To solve that, you can use advanced mode in the URL map

[image]

Start by setting the default backends for any URL and any path

[image]

Then add a new path rule and configure it like this, with a path rewrite to /

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Guillaume, I will try your suggestion and get back to you

Comment: This part is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect#partial-http-lb)

Comment: Thanks @guillaume. Also 1 URL map is only working, the others are not.